# Remove Space from Cell Value with Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Trying to remove all spaces from the value of a cell.

E3 contains employee full name (John Doe)

In O3 I have a formula that i copy when I open the sheet up and it does this automatically once pasted.  What I want is to have it run from a script.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E4," ",".")&("@companyname.net")
```

In my apps script I have the following that pulls the employee name.  This script is set to email but I want to add a function to put value in O3 as well.

```
      "<p><b>Employee Name: </b>" + row[4] + "</p>" +
```

How can I trim the above and add in the (.) with the @company.net email.

My Full Script

```
function sendEmails() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3; 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 23)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length-2; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var message = 

      "<p><b>Email From?: </b>" + row[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Request Type: </b>" + row[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Primary Location: </b>" + row[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Employee Name: </b>" + row[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Other Location(s): </b>" + row[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Title: </b>" + row[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Email Groups: </b>" + row[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Last 4: </b>" + row[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Phone #: </b>" + row[9] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Shirt Size: </b>" + row[10] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>District: </b>" + row[11] + "</p>" ;

        var completeMessage = 

      "<p><b>Employee Name: </b>" + row[4] + "</p>" + 
      "<p><b>Default Passwords (Datascape, Email): </b>" + row[12] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Fios ID: </b>" + row[13] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>New Email: </b>" + row[14] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Native Worker ID: </b>" + row[15] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>SSOID: </b>" + row[16] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Datascape ID: </b>" + row[17] + "</p>";




    Logger.log("Message:"+ message);

    var userMessage = 
        "Your request for a new ID has been submitted.  Please allow me a few hours to get this generated.  If this is a weekend, I will work this Monday morning.  If needed immediately please reach out to me directly at 978.929.5555<BR>Thank you";


   var cell = row[21]; 
    Logger.log("This is the Cell:" + cell);
    if (cell == "") { 
   var subject = "*** Automated Message *** ID CREATION REQUEST";
   Logger.log("Message Info" + message)   

     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: row[1],
     subject: "**** AUTOMATED MESSAGE **** ID Request",
     htmlBody: userMessage,
       noReply: true,
});

     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "number@vzwpix.com",
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message,
       noReply: true,
});

     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "myemail",
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message,
       noReply: true,
});

var setRow = parseInt(i) + startRow;
sheet.getRange(setRow, 22).setValue("Sent");
sheet.getRange(setRow, 13).setValue("password");
      sheet.getRange(setRow, 15).setFormula('=SUBSTITUTE(E3," ",".")&("@companyname.net")');



  }
}
}
```

Link to sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XnKnbEf07mqG2MrUslIuC9L0TzIFqbWDZHGL54ZSAEs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and the output values you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I cant share the sheet as the whole thing contains personal information.  Basically E3 contains employee name (FirstName LastName) which comes from a form.  O3 contains the email address that I create which is always firstname.lastname@company.net.  What I was looking for is a script to automatically create the email address based on the values of E3.  In my script already I am grabbing the Name row so I thought I could just use that row[4] to parse it and do this.

Comment: Actually here is a link ... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XnKnbEf07mqG2MrUslIuC9L0TzIFqbWDZHGL54ZSAEs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the result you want. I would like to confirm about your goal. You want to create from `John Doe` of the column "E" to `John.Doe@company.net` using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your first explanation, you said that the value of column "E" is used. But in your latest replying, you say that the value of column "B" is used. In your shared Spreadsheet, it seems that the value of column "B" is email address like `email@email.com`. I have to apologize. I cannot understand about your goal.

Comment: Column E has the name in the format like this (Stan Smith).  Then in column O I want the email address to populate automatically with (stan.smith@company.com) using scripting rather than using the formula I have been using.  That way on form submit it automatically creates it. Sorry im just not sure where Im not clear on the desired results...

Comment: Im sorry I see the confusion now.  Column E is the Name column

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to create from `John Doe` of the column "E" to `John.Doe@company.net` using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, do you want to use this function as one function? If you want to add the function to your script in your question, please tell me.

Comment: Yes I would like it as a script that does this task.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to create an email address from the name of the column "E".

  - You want to convert from `John Doe` of the column "E" to `John.Doe@company.net`.
- You want to put the created email to the column "O".
- You want to achieve this using one function with Google Apps Script.

I could understand like this from your replying. If this is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, please set the variable of `domain`. When you run `myFunction()`, the values from the column "E" are retrieved, and the converted values are put to the column "O".

```
function myFunction() {
  var domain = "@company.net";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange(3, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues();
  var convertedValues = values.map(function(row) {return [row[0].replace(/ /g, ".") + domain]});
  sheet.getRange(3, 15, convertedValues.length, convertedValues[0].length).setValues(convertedValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

Comment: Thank you.  Works how I want.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @David Morin Thank you for replying I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that this issue could be resolved by the cooperation of you. Thank you, too.